# When plugging a cell phone into my PC, I always get a Windows warning "You need to format the disk before you can use it"

Tags: windows-7, usb, formatting, smartphone

I have a Motorola Atrix phone (although I don't believe this is relevant to the issue). My PC is running Windows 7. When I plug the phone into the USB slot I always get the modal warning dialog that says "You need to format the disk in drive _: before you can use it"

Obviously this dialog is bogus for this scenario, does anyone know how to prevent it?

Comment: I think the article [_Windows 7 – disabling "you need to format the disk…" pop-up window_](https://pzolee.blogs.balabit.com/2010/03/windows-7-disabling-you-need-to-format-the-disk-pop-up-window/) might help.

Comment: Is the storage encrypted?

Comment: Have you updated the drivers of the phone?  Have you ever just let Windows format it?

Comment: @martineau I found that article when I was trying to find a solution for this issue, but it didn't help in this case.

Comment: So after thinking about this a little more I think I have the cause and a workaround. This is a work PC and we have software to block access to USB devices, so I think that when I plug in my phone Windows is thinking the drive is unreadable since it can't connect to it. Anyway I figured out if I configure my phone's USB settings to "None" I don't seem to see the warning.

Comment: If that works for you, answer and accept your own answer to make it easier for other folks with a similar problem to find a possible fix.

Comment: @martineau good idea, done! (although it won't let me accept it for 24 hours) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after thinking about this a little more I think I have the cause and a workaround. This is a work PC and we have software to block access to USB devices, so I think that when I plug in my phone Windows is thinking the drive is unreadable since it can't connect to it. Anyway I figured out if I configure my phone's USB settings to "None" I don't see the warning.